# Add two buttons for google social login

Tags: magento2

**Hey, I want to have 2 google customer login buttons in my store. I already set up one in the registration page, but i also want one in the case of if the user go to the checkout page without being logged into an account, i already have a popup that shows a magento default login button, but this popup doesn't have the google social login option... How can i add the google social login button and then redirect the user to the checkout page? I'm using mageplaza social-login module**

I added the button in the HTML file but the redirect return this error:
[image]